# How to cancel An Event in android

Tags: android, event-handling

I have written code for an application. It has some motion events.
The motion event has got Down, Move and Up states.
The event is bounded to a specific key until Up/Cancel happens.

But I want to cancel the motion event when Move happens, but not the entire application. **How can I cancel the motion event?**

Please give me some idea. Any helpful links/sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.camera_surface:
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   }
                  }
                return true;
         }
```

Whatever Event you want to disable just don,t put any code in that case. and at the end return the true value.

Comment: vikash thanks for help, but it is not working. what i want to do is if the user slides from 1 to 2.then down 1 on has done, then before up on 1 the user slides to 2. so it is a move event, now i want to cancel the event bounded to 1 and give it to 2 i.e. the up event of 1 should get canceled and down event of 2 should be recognized. please tell me how to do this...

Comment: I am looking for the same help.